# Run a task continuously without delay inside a Java TimerTask

Tags: java, loops, timertask

How do I run a specific set of instructions inside the TimerTask continuously without delay for a set amount of time ? Below are the codes I am attempting to implement the above.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Test started at: " + new Date());

        // Do something continuously without delay

        System.out.println("Test finished at: " + new Date());                           
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Do you want the task to both start and stop at particular times or delays in the future? If so, see my answer below, otherwise please clarify the question.

Comment: I would want the program to start immediately upon calling and then for 60 seconds continuously run a specific function without any stopping or sleeping in between and after the 60 seconds of running continuously, I want it to forcefully stop the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to the `schedule` method is the time to begin the timer task (or delay relative to now), not the length of time that the timer will execute for.

It's not completely clear from your question but I'm assuming you want the task to start and stop at particular times (or delays relative to now) in the future. If so, the way I would approach this is to create a `Thread` that does the task you need. Since a `TimerTask` is a `Runnable` that is executed as a `Thread` once the `Timer` starts it, you can just use an instance of that `TimerTask`. Ensure that `Runnable` contains a settable field like `running`. In that Thread, run your task in a while loop like this:

```
public void run() {
   while(running) { /* do my task */ }
}
```

Then, use one `Timer` to schedule the `Runnable` to start at the time you need. Use another Timer to set the `running` parameter of the same Thread to false at the time you want it to stop. The `running` parameter should be volatile to ensure that changes to it from the second timer Thread are seen by the first timer Thread immediately. So it would look something like this (not tested):

```
class StoppableTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private volatile boolean running = true;
    public void stopRunning() { this.running = false; }
    public void run() {
       while(running) { /* do my task */ }
    }
}

final StoppableTimerTask task = new StoppableTimerTask();
timer.schedule(task, startTime);
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       task.stopRunning();
    }
}, stopTime);
```

Depending on what your "something" is, you may also want to look into Thread interrupts. For example, if it is doing blocking IO, your code won't loop and check the `running` value until the blocking IO completes. Interrupting the thread (may) cause that to happen. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--. This may or may not work, and it can be tricky to get right, so if you need this Thread to exit as close to the desired time as possible, prefer running blocking I/O and similar operations with smaller timeouts so that the thread can check whether it should continue to run more often.

**UPDATE**: As per the comment indicating that the task should start right away, it becomes even simpler. The initial task doesn't even need to extend `TimerTask` -- it can just be a regular `Thread` that is started immediately. The timer is only needed to stop it at the specified future time.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @thotheolh Glad to help, note my update based on your response to my comment.